# OpenCV "imshow" function opens a lot of windows instead of replacing the frames on one window - Python

Tags: python, opencv

I have tried to capure my screen in real time (video) and show it with OpenCV in Python.

When I run my code, it opens a lot of windows instead of replacing the frames on one window only.

Please help :)

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from mss import mss

sct = mss()
monitor = {'top': 0, 'left': 0, 'width': 1920, 'height': 1080}

while True:
    img = sct.grab(monitor)
    cv2.imshow("Netstream", np.array(img))
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this problem occurs, when I do not use the same name for the window.

**A new window opens with each iteration (`i` is an iteration):**

```
cv2.imshow(i, image)
```

**A single window is used:**

```
cv2.imshow("Main", image)
```

Answer (score -2):

It opens only one window but seems as if its more than one because its capturing your own screen and displaying over that. Hence as soon as one window opens, your program captures the screen and displays a new frame on the stream and this process continues on which creates an effect of opening multiple windows. It might help if you capture one screen and display on another